# How to rewrite text between links using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link inside a div. Inside the link (between the ), I have text displayed. I want to change that text when the cursor hovers over the link.

***One thing I forgot to mention is that I want the text to be temporarily changed (i.e. only when it's hovered over).

Here's my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ZEZEME/kapt4sL6/5/

This is what my code looks like.

HTML

```
<div id="imgDiv"></div>
```

CSS

```
#imgDiv {
width: 200px; 
height:200px; 
background-color: gray;
}
```

JS

```
var title = "World War II Plane Crashes in National Parks";
var url = "https://www.nps.gov/articles/WWIIPlaneCrashes.htm"

$(imgDiv).append($('<a href="' + url + '" id=link>'+ title +'</a>'));
```

(I'm working with APIs, and .append is how I create the links. I need to dynamically create them to the div in JavaScript).

This is what I've tried:

```
$(imgDiv).append($('<a href="' + url + '" id=link>'+ title +'</a>').css('text-decoration', 'none').hover(function(e) { 
        console.log($(e.target).text("NEWWW"));
}));
```

This permanently changes the text (as opposed to only when hovered over).

```
$(imgDiv).append($('<a href="' + url + '" id=link>'+ title +'</a>').css('text-decoration', 'none').hover(function(e) { 
    function(e) {
        console.log($(e.target).text("NEWWW"));
    }, 
    function(e) {
        console.log($(e.target).text("OLDDD"));
    }
```

This gives me an error. Can anyone help?

Comment: As was mentioned in one of your previous questions with `textContent` not being exposed by jQuery, neither is `innerHTML`.  You need to familiarize yourself with the fact that jQuery does not expose Element properties directly.  You have to use prop() for property access.  Or in this case, changing the html is `html(newHtml)`

Comment: Also `val(newValue)`.  I would highly suggest you take a chance to read over https://learn.jquery.com/ .  There is tons of literature there that is helpful for an individual getting started with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mouseover` to detect when the mouse moves over the link, you can then use `mouseout` to see when it leaves the link.

You also want to use `text()` as `val()` is for form fields.

```js
var title = "World War II Plane Crashes in National Parks";
var url = "https://www.nps.gov/articles/WWIIPlaneCrashes.htm"

$('#imgDiv').append($('<a href="' + url + '" id=link>'+ title +'</a>'))

// Create an event to watch "a" tags
$('#imgDiv a').on('mouseover', (e) => {
  $(e.target).text('I am some new text')
})
// Comment this out if you don't want it to go back on mouse out.
.on('mouseout', (e) => {
  $(e.target).text(title)
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
#imgDiv {
  width: 200px; 
  height:200px; 
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgDiv"></div>
```